# validar existencia antes de insertar

Tags: c#, mysql

Hola buenas tardes a todos, anteriormente hice esta misma pregunta pero se me recomendo que abrirera un nuevo hilo, tengo que validar que antes de hacer un insert verifique si ese registro existe. En caso de que exista, me muestre un mensaje de alerta y me pregunte si quiero llamar a la edicion del mismo, si no existe, que me permita pasar a la funcion de insercion.

Para esto, tengo un Procedimiento almacenado en MYSQL que mediante un COUNT me dice si X id existe X veces en la base de datos.

ahora, en c#, tengo un boton guardar con el siguiente codigo:

```
    private void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DateTime fd = Convert.ToDateTime(dtpFechaNac.Value);
        String fnacimiento = fd.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd");

        //label15.Text = fnacimiento;

        //VALIDAR EXISTENCIA DE RUT


        try
        {
            string respuesta = "";

            //validamos los campos obligatorios
            if (this.txtDocumento.Text == string.Empty || this.txtNombres.Text == string.Empty ||
                this.txtApePat.Text == string.Empty || this.txtDireccion.Text == string.Empty ||
                this.txtFono.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                mensajeError("Faltan datos por ingresar, favor verificar");
                error.SetError(txtDocumento, "Debe Ingresar Numero de Documento");
                error.SetError(txtApePat, "Debe Ingresar Numero de Documento");
                error.SetError(txtDireccion, "Debe Ingresar Numero de Documento");
                error.SetError(txtFono, "Debe Ingresar Numero de Documento");
                error.SetError(txtNombres, "Debe Ingresar Numero de Documento");
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.isNuevo)
                {
                   respuesta = negociosFuncionario.insertar(
                   this.txtDocumento.Text,
                   this.txtNombres.Text,
                   this.txtApePat.Text,
                   this.txtApeMat.Text,
                   this.dtpFechaNac.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"),
                   this.cmbSexo.Text,
                   this.txtDireccion.Text,
                   Convert.ToInt32(this.txtFono.Text),
                   this.txtCorreo.Text,
                   this.cmbPrevSalud.Text,
                   this.cmbPrevSocial.Text,
                   this.txtComentarios.Text
                  );
                }
                else
                {
                   respuesta = negociosFuncionario.editar(
                   Convert.ToInt32(this.txtCodFuncionario.Text),
                   this.txtDocumento.Text,
                   this.txtNombres.Text,
                   this.txtApePat.Text,
                   this.txtApeMat.Text,
                   this.dtpFechaNac.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"),
                   this.cmbSexo.Text,
                   this.txtDireccion.Text,
                   Convert.ToInt32(this.txtFono.Text),
                   this.txtCorreo.Text,
                   this.cmbPrevSalud.Text,
                   this.cmbPrevSocial.Text,
                   this.txtComentarios.Text
                  );

                }

                if (respuesta.Equals("OK"))
                {
                    if (this.isNuevo)
                    {
                        this.mensajeOK("REGISTRO INSERTADO CON EXITO EN LA BASE DE DATOS");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.mensajeOK("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO CON EXITO");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.mensajeError(respuesta);
                }

                this.isNuevo = false;
                this.isEditar = false;
                this.botones();
                this.limpiarControles();
                this.cargarGrilla();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

y en mi capa datos, tengo el metodo validar de la siguiente forma:

```
        public int validarExistencia(string rut)
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        con.ConnectionString = conexion.cadenaConexion;
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "spValidaExistFuncionario";

        //ID AUTOINCREMENTAL
        MySqlParameter parIdFunc = new MySqlParameter();
        parIdFunc.ParameterName = "@rut1";
        parIdFunc.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
        parIdFunc.Size = 25;
        parIdFunc.Value = rut;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parIdFunc);

        //EJECUCION DEL COMANDO
        int respuesta = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        return respuesta ;
    }
```

lo que no entiendo bien, es como y donde deberia hacer el llamado a es funcion de validacion.

Saludos a todos, agradezco desde ya

Comment: si estas usando mysql deberias tener por cada registro una identificador diferente al id en la DB eso te permite que al insertar si existe ese identificador te lanza un error el cual lo puedes capturar con un try y lanxar un mensaje que diga que ya existe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En otras tecnologias puedes crear un unique constraint, puedes definir una o varias columnas en esta y al tratar de insertar un registro existente te marcara el error.

Creo que este link te puede ayudar. 
https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/unique.php

> **¿Cuál es una restricción única (Unique constraint) en MySQL?**  Una
>   restricción única es un solo campo o combinación de campos que define
>   un registro de manera única. Algunos de los campos pueden contener
>   valores nulos siempre que la combinación de valores sea única.

Crear Restricción única - Usar una instrucción CREATE TABLE

La sintaxis para crear una restricción única usando una instrucción `CREATE TABLE` en MySQL es:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  ...

  CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (uc_col1, uc_col2, ... uc_col_n)
);
```

Comment: en MySQL funciona perfecto el Constraint UNIQUE solo se declara nameProduct VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL

Comment: @dbamex debes revisar [answer] para realizar respuestas, revisa lo relacionado a los enlaces, agregué mas información a la respuesta por si el link deja de funcionar, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Solo cambia el `if (this.isNuevo)` por `if (clase.validarExistencia(id_validar) == 0)`

Comment: me arroja error en la linea :  //EJECUCION DEL COMANDO
        int respuesta = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: qué dice el error?

Comment: "No se controlo NullReferenceException" . Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.NullReferenceException' en MySql.Data.dll

Comment: Tal vez el ExecuteScalar respondió con un null, solo hay que validar

Comment: ahi es donde no se como validar esa excepcion, si trae null

Comment: Puedes poner un try-catch https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions o con un if antes de convertir a int donde el else devuelva 0 'res = cmd.ExecuteScalar();if(res != null) conversion else devolver cero' si no funciona el null prueba con DBNull.Value